# Тотальный диктант

Tags: общие-вопросы

Вопрос, не относящийся к самому русскому языку.

Существует такое мероприятие - ["Тотальный диктант"](http://totaldict.ru/). На мой взгляд, инициатива полезная.

1. Кто-нибудь вообще ходил?
2. Как относитесь к такому мероприятию? Это вообще осмысленно? Или очередной распил денег и пиар каких-либо организаций?
3. Какие другие способы проверки собственной грамотности существуют? Желательно бесплатные и чтоб контроль был со стороны (т.е. объективный)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаю об этой инициативе Новосибирского госуниверситета давно, читал тексты тотальных диктантов прошлых лет, испльзовал их в работе с учениками и студентами. Считаю, что эта идея, родившаяся "снизу" еще в 2004 году, вяло развивалась, пока держалась на голом энтузиазме. Постепенно круг желающих проверить свою грамотность расширялся. Этому способствовал появившийся интерес к данной идее со стороны СМИ, интернет-сообщества. В этом году произошел "прорыв": писали диктант более 30 тыс человек в 35 странах мира, к проведению акции подключились медийные, узнаваемые  лица, например А.Кортнев, Л.Ярмольник, текст написала Д.Рубина (в прошлом году _ З.Прилепин, еще ранее - Д.Быков). Насколько мне известно, пока что все строилось на минимальных материальных затратах (помещения учебных заведений и впервые бланки-листы для записывания текста). Посмотрим, как будут развиваться события дальше, не забюрократизируют ли самое идею. А вообще инициатива хороша: это привлечение внимания к родному слову. Нашему сайту надо бы подключиться к этому отрадному явлению! Добавляю ссылку на сайт "Тотальный диктант" http://totaldict.ru/

Comment: ссылочку бы на последний...

Comment: http://totaldict.ru/

Comment: > впервые бланки-листы для записывания текста

бланков не хватило, писали на обычных листах А4 (чистых).

Answer (score 0):

~1. Я - нет, знакомых ходивших не знаю.
~2. Пиар - да, возможно, распил - категорически нет, там пилить нечего.
~3. Что такое со стороны? Вы не доверяете собственной способности сравнить ваш вариант с ответом? тут другое надо спрашивать. А насколько вообще объективны (или показательны) подобные экзаменационные или тестовые проверки. МоЖно и еще глубже копнуть, спросив, а что вообще такое грамотность? Я лично однозначного ответа на эти вопросы не знаю.

Если же говорить о ТД вообще, вне этих вопросов, то слышал о нем давно, большого энтузиазма не вызывает. Хотя, если кому-то поможет стать немного грамотнее или преодолеть комплексы - буду только рад. 
очень бы хотелось услышать мнение профессиональной среды, причем не тщательно отыильтрованное, как подаётся обычно в СМИ, а во всей полемике.

Comment: Кстати, о полемике. Единственная проблема, которую я пока что вижу, --это подбор для диктантов текстов, в которых нередко встречаются спорные случаи, особенно в отношении пунктуации. Полемика всегда идет по этой проблеме.

Comment: По просьбе А. добавляю ссылку на сайт "Тотальный диктант" http://totaldict.ru/

Comment: @behemothus, по п.3 - дело в том, что текст (произвольно взятый) можно прочесть по-разному. Как следствие, будет разная расстановка знаков препинаний теми, кто этот текст воспринимает и записывает. Тут же ведь интересно попытаться какую же пунктуацию имел в виду автор.

Проверить же просто орфографию - неинтересно (это можно и самому, просто сверившись со словариком).

по п.2 - рекламная сторона была. Это 100%. Тот же канал "Домашний" поучаствовал... Да и некоторая реклама площадок, где проводилось мероприятие.

Comment: >По просьбе А. добавляю ссылку на сайт "Тотальный диктант" http://totaldict.ru/

Спасибо от b.
Только речь шла о текстах самого диктатнта, а не адресе сайта.

Comment: Уважаемый А.! По ссылке, которую я указал, заходите на сайт, а там уже опубликованы вчерашние тексты Д.Рубиной

Comment: Тексты диктанта этого года можно посмотреть на Грамоте.ру (gramota.ru).